# Scrollview overlapping on fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

The following is my activity_scrolling.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.visualcovid_19.ScrollingActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The following is my content_scrolling.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".ScrollingActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/country_card_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/country_card_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But, I end up getting the scroll view overlapped on map fragment and right below `AppBarLayout`
a screenshot is attached below.

[image]

I want the scroll view to start at the end of the map fragment and the initial scroll should take the `AppBarLayout` and the fragment below it to the top as usual and the rest scroll view should be able to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling" from content_scrolling.xml. Also, try to not include your cards, use the full code.